# Does anyone know why the html duplicates when im searching?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im doing a searcher page where i place an input and acording to the data in the input, it search in the database for similar articles and displays in the boxes. but when i search something another header and input appears in the page.
duplicated header and input

[image]
Ive tried asking chatgpt but it couldnt help me. I also searched but couldnt find anything similar.

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["user"] == "" || $_SESSION["premium"] == "") {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}

$valorInput = isset($_GET["valor"]) ? $_GET["valor"] : "";

include "dbconnect.php";

$resultados = array();

if (!empty($valorInput)) {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, description, link, imagelink, price FROM Articulos WHERE description LIKE ?");
        $param = "%$valorInput%";
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultados[] = '<div class="template">
                <img src="' . $row['imagelink'] . '" alt="' . $row['description'] . '">
                <p>' . $row['name'] . '</p>
                <p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>
                <p>Precio: ' . $row['price'] . '</p>
            </div>';
        }

        $stmt->close();
        echo implode('', $resultados);
        exit();
    }
}

$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/inicio.css">
    <title>Buscador de Productos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>    
        <h1>Buscador de Productos</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="search-container">
        <input type="text" id="search-box" oninput="actualizarVariable()" placeholder="Buscar productos...">
        <div id="search-results" class="search-results-container"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="result-container" class="container">
        <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            echo '<div class="template">
            <img src="imagen1.jpg" alt="';
            echo $valorInput;
            echo '">
            <p>Descripción del Producto 1</p>
            </div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <script>
        function actualizarVariable() {
            var valorInput = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("result-container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "inicio.php?valor=" + valorInput, true);
            xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should separate the PHP code that queries the database and returns the search results into a different PHP file. This way, the AJAX request will only fetch the search results instead of the entire page content.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` is not in spec, it is just something that frameworks such jQuery and others happen to do, so checking for it won't work.

Comment: your xhttp.open and xhttp.send commands are running on every readystatechange... I'm not sure you want that.  You're also returning the whole page... along with the script...  you should send a POST to an endpoint (php page) that only returns the data/http you need to populate the "result-container".

Comment: Remove the `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])` clause (but keep the code inside it).